# Elemental proof of Zariski's lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, extension-field

I'm trying to use induction but I don't know how to apply the induction hypothesis.

**Lemma**. Let K be a finitely generated algebra over a field k. If K is a field, then K is a finite field extension of k.

**Proof**. We know $K=k[a_1,\dotsc,a_n]$, we can suppose $a_i \in K\setminus k$. We're going to see every $a_i$ is algebraic over $k$, because if $a_i$ is algebraic, $k[a_i]$ is a finite field extension. By induction, $K$ is a finite field extension.

We proceed by induction. If $n=1$, $K=k[a_1]$. For every $p\in K$ $\exists b_0,\dotsc,b_s \in k$ such that
$$
p = \sum_{i=0}^s b_i a_1^i $$
Taking $p=a_1^{-1}$, it's clear that $a_1$ it's a root of $f(X) = -1+\sum_{i=0}^s b_i X^{i+1}$, so $a_1$ is algebraic over $k$.

Now I have to apply induction hypothesis. We $\exists f:{k[a_1,\dotsc,a_n]}\to{K}$ surjective, such that $K\cong k[a_1,\dotsc,a_n]/\ker(f)$. Obviusly, $\ker(f)$ is maximal ideal.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: This statement is false as written without further clarifying assumptions. Do you intend for $K$ to be finitely generated as a module? (You should, but remembering the difference between fg as a module and fg as a ring is important here.) How do you exclude $k\times k$ with component-wise addition and multiplication? Currently your problem allows this, but $k\times k$ is not even an integral domain.

Comment: @KReiser I don't understand you, sorry. I'm proving this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma

Comment: My apologies - I misread the statement of your question (I missed "$K$ is a field").